# Obtain substring using awk

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, awk

All, I want to use AWK to split the below String as first part.

How to write the AWK expression?

```
#!/bin/bash

function parsePackageName()
{
  #....... here I want to get the String "pp-demo-mid"
  #        from "pp-demo-mid-1.0-212.noarch"
}
```

Sample Inputs:

```
pp-demo-mid-1.0-212.noarch
pp-1.0-212.noarch
pp-xx-1.0-212.noarch
```

Desired Outputs:

```
pp-demo-mid
pp
pp-xx
```

that means , I need to parse the first part before version number .

Comment: Format of regex is very unclear. consider providing more examples

Comment: requires : 1.  echo XXX-1.6.6-5.i386 | awk -F- '{ print $1}'  --> XXX . 2 echo XXX-UU-M-1.4.3-2.noarch.rpm | awk -F- '{ print $1}'  --> XXX, but I want to get XXX-UU-M

Comment: Please update this in question. Does this mean any name preceding version numbers?

Comment: Without awk , just implement the function is OK

Comment: looks like SO is way ahead of you - it's already highlighted the stuff you don't want in red :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? It divides the string at the first -number.

```
awk -F"-[0-9]" '{print $1}' file
pp-demo-mid
pp
pp-xx
```

Or you can be more specific and devide after first -x.x, where x is a number

```
awk -F"-[0-9][.][0-9]" '{print $1}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt using `sed`

```
sed -r 's/([^0-9]+)-.*/\1/'
```

`([^0-9]+)` will capture all non digit characters in `\1`